# Why doesn't JavaFX TextField listener work?

Tags: java, javafx

I want to add a listener to a textField in a window that appears when I press a button on a previous window. The problem is that the listener doesn't work at all. It doesn't detect any change.

```
public class WindowTwoController {

private Stage stage;

@FXML
private TextField imieTF = new TextField();


public void show() throws IOException {

    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("winTwo.fxml"));
    Parent root = loader.load();

    stage = new Stage();
    stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);

    stage.setTitle("Sell Art");
    stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 500, 500));

    imieTF.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        System.out.println("textfield changed from " + oldValue + " to " + newValue);
    });

    stage.showAndWait();

}
```

I'm changing the value of the textField, but nothing is printed out to the console. The show method is called when a button is pressed on the previous window. Please help me. This is my winTwo.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Separator?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<GridPane alignment="center" hgap="10" prefHeight="441.0" prefWidth="500.0" vgap="10" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.172-ea" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="windowTwo.WindowTwoController">
<columnConstraints>
    <ColumnConstraints />
</columnConstraints>
<rowConstraints>
    <RowConstraints />
</rowConstraints>
<children>
    <VBox prefHeight="354.0" prefWidth="455.0">
        <children>
            <Label alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="45.0" prefWidth="457.0" text="Sprzedaż dzieła">
                <font>
                    <Font size="30.0" />
                </font>
            </Label>
            <Separator prefWidth="200.0" />
            <GridPane prefHeight="139.0" prefWidth="455.0">
                <columnConstraints>
                    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                </columnConstraints>
                <rowConstraints>
                    <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                    <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                </rowConstraints>
                <children>
                    <Label alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="220.0" text="Imię">
                        <font>
                            <Font size="28.0" />
                        </font>
                    </Label>
                    <Label alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="220.0" text="Nazwisko" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
                        <font>
                            <Font size="28.0" />
                        </font>
                    </Label>
                    <TextField fx:id="imieTF" GridPane.columnIndex="1">
                        <GridPane.margin>
                            <Insets right="20.0" />
                        </GridPane.margin></TextField>
                    <TextField fx:id="nazwiskoTF" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
                        <GridPane.margin>
                            <Insets right="20.0" />
                        </GridPane.margin>
                    </TextField>
                </children>
            </GridPane>
            <Separator prefWidth="200.0" />
            <Label alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="450.0" text="Klient powracający">
                <font>
                    <Font size="22.0" />
                </font>
            </Label>
            <Separator prefWidth="200.0" />
            <GridPane prefHeight="126.0" prefWidth="455.0">
                <columnConstraints>
                    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                </columnConstraints>
                <rowConstraints>
                    <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                    <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                </rowConstraints>
                <children>
                    <Label alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="220.0" text="Poziom Zaprzyjaźnienia" textFill="#00000080">
                        <font>
                            <Font size="19.0" />
                        </font>
                    </Label>
                    <ComboBox fx:id="cb" opacity="0.5" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="207.0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
                    <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="175.0" text="Akceptuj" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
                        <GridPane.margin>
                            <Insets left="25.0" />
                        </GridPane.margin>
                    </Button>
                    <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="175.0" text="Anuluj" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
                        <GridPane.margin>
                            <Insets left="27.0" />
                        </GridPane.margin>
                    </Button>
                </children>
            </GridPane>
        </children>
    </VBox>
</children>
</GridPane>
```

Comment: Sidenote: I don't know why "public void show() throws IOException {" isn't shown as part of the code. It is.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. As to formatting: the line needs to start with 4 spaces

Comment: Is the textfield imieTF the actual one being displayed in the Stage you are displaying? If not then it would not be strange for the event not to propegate to the imieTF

Comment: Your `TextField` imieTF does not seem to be added to any window. If this imieTF is part of winTwo.fxml, it should be managed in the winTwo controller.

Answer (score 3):

You should add an anotation to the private member imieTF like so

```
public class WindowTwoController {
  @FXML
  private TextField imieTF;

  @FXML
  private void initialize() {
      imieTF.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> 
       {
         System.out.println("textfield changed from " + oldValue + " to " + newValue);
       });
  }

  public static void show() {
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("winTwo.fxml"));
    Parent root = loader.load();

    stage = new Stage();
    stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);

    stage.setTitle("Sell Art");
    stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 500, 500));
    stage.showAndWait();
  }
}
```

This should bind the TextField instance to the controller. But from what I can find out the FXML will create a new instance of WindowTwoController when the window belonging to the fxml file gets created.

Also see https://www.callicoder.com/javafx-fxml-form-gui-tutorial/ for a basic example on how this works.

Note that all manipulations of the textfield should be part of the JavaFX flow and cannot be done in a manual instance of WindowTwoController. Keep in mind that JavaFX will create it's own instance of WindowTwoController during the `loader.load();` operation.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to copy that part over to the question. The @FXML tag is there. I'm terribly sorry about that.

Comment: It may be there, but you should not instantiate it in the java code. It should only be `@FXML private TextField imieTF;` as mentionned by @GerbenJongerius instead of `@FXML private TextField imieTF = new TextField();`.

Comment: You should also annotate your methods 'show' with the @FXML to trigger it being called after JavaFX creates the controller. How else would it know to call that method. How is this method being invoked, as it is part of the WindowTwoController but that should be instantiated by JavaFX and not by you.

Comment: When I change it to  "@FXML private TextField imieTF;" i get a nullPointerException at line "imieTF.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {...". Does anyone know why?

Comment: I've expanded the answer a bit. You need to keep in mind that the instance of WindowTwoController you are calling the method `show` on is not the same instance that JavaFX is creating when it is loading the file `winTwo.fxml`.